# how do I fix my code in order to display one table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to render my dynamic JSON , but I am getting a table per result when it should be rendered in the same table.. what's happening this? my dummy array is a model from my backend api

```
const arr = [
  {
      "Demo": [
          {
              "_id": "T08210",
              "name": "tilehaha",
              "tags": [
                  "Demo"
              ],
              "queries": [],
              "urls": [],
              "max_leght": [],
              "count_items": []
          },
      ],
    }
  ];

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <div>
  {arr.map(obj =>
    Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => (
        <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr key={key}>
            <th scope="col">{key}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{value.activityType}</td>
            <td>{value.durationInSeconds}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )))}
</div>
  );
}
```

I need to place in the blue section as heading `2671161009, and 2671161249` , and their child items as the following
[image: layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it *seems* like maybe this is what you want:

**Note to future views -- now not applicable to the changed question**:

```
const modArray = Object.keys(arr[0]).map(i => {
  return {id: i, ...arr[0][i]}
});

const rowKeys = Object.keys(modArray[0]).filter(i => i !== "id")

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <div>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          {modArray.map(i => <th key={i.id}>{i.id}</th>)}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            {modArray.map(item => <td key={item.id}>{item.activityType}</td>)}
          </tr>
          <tr>
            {modArray.map(item => <td key={item.id}>{item.durationInSeconds}</td>)}
          </tr>

          {/* Or, do it dynamically */}
          {rowKeys.map(rowKey => <tr key={rowKey}>
            {modArray.map(item => <td key={item.id}>{item[rowKey]}</td>)}
          </tr>)}
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  );
  }
```

Note that at the top of that code sample, I transformed your input into a more usable format. Your beginning `arr`, for example, was an array of just 1 object, which had multiple keys, which really seemed to be the array you wanted to iterate over.

Hopefully this is at least close to what you're looking for.

**Update 2, based on your changed question**:

```
export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          {arr[0]["Demo"].map(i => <th key={i._id}>{i._id}</th>)}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            {arr[0]["Demo"].map(item => <td key={item._id}>{item.name}</td>)}
          </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  );
  }
```

Comment: sure, but my headings are `2671161009, and 2671161249` how do I modify in order to do so? @jnpdx

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what you want the table to look like. How/why would you have a table that has rows from different items in the y axis and then headings from those different items in the Y axis. If you had three items, would you then have a third column in the heading with the id from that item? If you draw/explain how that part works, I'm sure I can update my answer.

Comment: @ jnpdx I update my question with a draw how I want to represent my data

Comment: Okay -- the drawing is a little vague, but I think maybe I understand the general idea now. Post updated.

Comment: thanks, but I updated my `arr` model in order to test my real dummy API , and when I tried to load . it only loads headings, but table body no since from obj is an array of objects . how can I modify your example to make it work properly?

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect the new data. The new data looks *completely* different than the old stuff did, so I'm not really sure what you want in the table rows, but I've shown you how to get started. Please consider upvoting the answer if this is helpful to you.

Comment: @jndpx , but ` "Demo": [` are the same keying dynamic as before . that;s why I want to handle that dynamic to access to array of objects and perform item.property

Comment: But the content is totally different - it's arrays of information. Displaying that to the user is different than just string and number values. You can use my previous approach to get the dynamic keys. I left all of those in the answer as well as my now-updated-answer. If you have a specific question about displaying the new values, perhaps best to start a new question, or at least say *exactly* what you want in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {arr.map(obj => Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ( 
            <th scope="col">{key}</th>
        )))}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {arr.map(obj => Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ( 
          <tr>
            <td>{value.activityType}</td>
            <td>{value.durationInSeconds}</td>
          </tr>
     )))}
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
{arr.map(obj =>
    Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => (
        <table class="table">
```

here you have put the entire table inside the loop instead of putting a single table row. So on every iteration it generates a new table. To resolve this issue, try this:

Try this:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Heading 1</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {
    arr.map(obj =>
        Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ( 
          <tr>
            <td>{value.activityType}</td>
            <td>{value.durationInSeconds}</td>
          </tr>
     )))}
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: sure, but how do I handle the `2671161249` as a heading as the image?